# Parse.com can't read facebook user details when app restart

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using Parse Version 1.2.19 and I can't access a facebook user's name.

```
if ([PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]) {
// Create Facebook Request for user's details
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    NSString *displayName = result[@"name"];
    if (displayName) {
        self.title =[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Welcome %@!", nil), displayName];
    }
  }else{
     NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
  }
 }];
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x29e24040 {com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
  body = {
    error = {
      code = 2500;
        message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
        type = OAuthException;
      };
  };
  code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400}
```

These 2 posts claim the issue is fixed in the latest parse version:

https://www.parse.com/questions/error-when-trying-to-reauthorise-facebook-user
https://www.parse.com/questions/oauthexception-code-2500-an-active-access-token-must-be-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I needed this:

```
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
```

Before calling the request.  That line of code wasn't being called when the app just reloaded.